# Package `exec-path-from-shell` isn't setting PATH variables from `.zshenv` on MacOS

Tags: use-package, path, environment, zsh, exec-path

I'm running a GUI Emacs compiled from the `master` git branch on MacOS El Capitan. I'm using the package `exec-path-from-shell` to set several environment variables I have configured in my `~/.zshenv` file. However, none of them inherited in Emacs. `GOPATH` and `SHELL` are not set and `PATH` is not the PATH I have configured in my `~/.zshenv Currently I have the package configured with

```
(use-package exec-path-from-shell
  :ensure t
  :defer f
  :config
  (exec-path-from-shell-copy-env "GOPATH")
  (exec-path-from-shell-copy-env "SHELL")
  (exec-path-from-shell-copy-env "PATH")
  (when (memq window-system '(mac ns x))
    (exec-path-from-shell-initialize)))
```

After launching Emacs, `M-x getenv` for `PATH` returns `/usr/bin:/usr/sbin/:/bin/:/sbin`

However, executing `shell-command` via `M-!` with `zsh -l -i -c 'echo $PATH`returns the PATH as I have set it in my `~/.zshenv` file.

The `~/.zshenv` looks like

```
export PATH="/Users/idclark/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/texbin:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:/Users/idclark/Library/Android/sdk/tools:/Users/idclark/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools"
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home)"
export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"
export NVM_DIR="~/.nvm"
export GOPATH="/Users/idclark/go/bin"
```

Is this a problem with my zsh config or how how I'm initializing the `exec-path-from-shell` package?

Comment: Apple screwed up the zsh configuration files. /etc/zprofile resets the path, but is called after ~/.zshenv. IIRC this doesn't affect normal login shells. My solution was to rename /etc/zprofile to /etc/zshenv, iirc (I'm not at my Mac just now.)

Answer (score 5):

You should remove `:defer f`, because you don't want `exec-path-from-shell` to be defer loaded and you are going to use function from it when Emacs starts. Try something like the following

```
(use-package exec-path-from-shell
  :ensure t
  :if (memq window-system '(mac ns x))
  :config
  (setq exec-path-from-shell-variables '("PATH" "GOPATH"))
  (exec-path-from-shell-initialize))
```

(I don't know why you need to set `SHELL`, Emacs sets it automatically and correctly for me, like `HOME`)

If you are not sure if you are using `use-package` correctly, expand it via something like `emacs-lisp-macroexpand` and check the result.

Comment: I also had to `(setenv "SHELL" "/usr/local/bin/zsh")`, but now all of my env variables are inherited in Emacs correctly.