# How to get Exec-path-from-shell working in Spacemacs

Tags: magit, spacemacs, path, exec-path

I'm using the latest version of emacs, with and without a custom MacOS build ([homebrew-emacs-plus](https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus)). So, I'm trying to use spacemacs on MacOS, and I can't get it to pick up the `$PATH` on my host system. So when I try to run a command like `M-x magit-status`, I get the error message.

```
apply: Searching for program: No such file or directory, git
```

Spacemacs is using Steve Purcell's [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell). This [SO question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30397/package-exec-path-from-shell-isnt-setting-path-variables-from-zshenv-on-ma) isn't quite solving it. And I've tried the below configuration (not using exec-path-from-shell), but no dice. I can get it working on my custom emacs configuration. But I’m trying to transition to spacemacs. And this is a blocker. Anyone know howto solve this?

```
(let ((path (shell-command-to-string ". ~/.bash_profile; echo -n $PATH")))
  (setenv "PATH" path)
  (setq exec-path 
        (append
         (split-string-and-unquote path ":")
         exec-path)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, solved this one. It turns out that there was an `export PATH` in my ***.bashrc*** (as well as ***.bash-profile***). ***exec-path-from-shell*** doesn't like this, and only wants that export to happen in ***.bash-profile***. This warning message gives a hint of the expectation. But I didn't realize that the package doesn't work if the condition isn't satisfied.

Hth

> Warning (emacs): You appear to be setting environment variables
>   ("PATH") in your .bashrc or .zshrc: those files are only read by
>   interactive shells, so you should instead set environment variables in
>   startup files like .bash_profile or .zshenv. Refer to your shell's man
>   page for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Spacemacs, but if it's just magit you need to get working right now, you may want to try setting `magit-git-executable` to the full path (e.g., '/usr/local/bin/git' instead of 'git') as a workaround to getting your path set correctly.

Comment: Hey @willy-lee. I actually already have this working for my own hand-rolled emacs config. I'm trying to get the equivalent `exec-path-from-shell` (which is what spacemacs uses) functionality working. I tried this on both GNU Emacs 24.5.1 and 25.1.1, and running into this blocker for both versions.